# Laravel put NULL inside quotes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, null, quotes

I'd like to make union query with Laravel Eloquent.
When we proceed UNION queries, there should be the same number of selected columns in both queries.
To skip that rule I would like to select NULL as `Column_name`,
but Laravel API automatically replaces NULL with 'Null' and that causes an error "`Null` column is not existed".

How to remove these automatically added quotes from Null?

That is what I have:
The first query:

```
...->select("Calendars.*","Services.Id as IdService","Services.Name as ServiceName","NULL as Price")
```

The second query:

```
...->select("Calendars.*","Services.Id as IdService","Services.Name as ServiceName","PaidService.Price")
```

Result is:

```
...union (select `Calendars`.*, `Services`.`Id` as `IdService`, `Services`.`Name` as `ServiceName`, `NULL` as `Price` from `Calendars`
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [DB::raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) for this. It will stop laravel from modifying the statement and parse it as is.

```
DB::raw("NULL as Price")
```

which will make the first query

```
...->select("Calendars.*",
            "Services.Id as IdService",
            "Services.Name as ServiceName",
            DB::raw("NULL as Price"))
```